# Double grouping data by bins AND time with pandas

Tags: numpy, pandas, group-by, grouping, binning

I am trying to bin values from a timeseries (hourly and subhourly temperature values) within a time window.
That is, from original hourly values, I'd like to extract binned values on a daily, weekly or monthly basis.
I have tried to combine `groupby`+`TimeGrouper(" ")` with `pd.cut`, with poor results.

I have came across a nice function from this [tutorial](http://wrobstory.github.io/2013/04/real-world-pandas-1.html), which suggests to map the data (associating to each value with its mapped range on the next column) and then grouping according to that.

```
def map_bin(x, bins):
    kwargs = {}
    if x == max(bins):
        kwargs['right'] = True
    bin = bins[np.digitize([x], bins, **kwargs)[0]]
    bin_lower = bins[np.digitize([x], bins, **kwargs)[0]-1]
    return '[{0}-{1}]'.format(bin_lower, bin)

df['Binned'] = df['temp'].apply(map_bin, bins=freq_bins)
```

However, applying this function results in an IndexError: index *n* is out of bounds for axis 0 with size *n*.

Ideally, I'd like make this work and apply it to achieve a double grouping at the same time: one by bins and one by timegrouper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**
It appears that my earlier attempt was causing problems because of the double-indexed columns. I have simplified to something that seems to work much better.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
xaxis = np.linspace(0,50)
temps = pd.Series(data=xaxis,name='temps')
times = pd.date_range(start='2015-07-15',periods=50,freq='6H')
temps.index = times

bins = [0,10,20,30,40,50]

temps.resample('W').agg(lambda series:pd.value_counts(pd.cut(series,bins),sort=False)).unstack()
```

This outputs:

```
           (0, 10]  (10, 20]    (20, 30]    (30, 40]    (40, 50]
2015-07-19       9        10           0           0           0
2015-07-26       0         0          10          10           8
2015-08-02       0         0           0           0           2
```

Comment: Alton, I would like to group both by bins and by day/week, at the same time

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want all measurements from the same time to be averaged, and then to group those by day, week, and month?

Comment: ha, that would be too simple!!
Say I have one sensor recording a room temperature at hourly intervals (it is actually 10/15mins, but I have resampled it in pandas).
Thus my df is very simple: first column: timestamp(indexed), second column: temperature

If my bins were [20, 22,24,26,28,30], I'd like to group the data in such a way that I know how many datapoints (i.e. how many hourly temperature values) were in the 20< <22, how many 22< <24 etc. for each day and for each week .

Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, yes that makes much more sense, I appreciate the clarification.

Comment: Apologies, I though I had been quite clear but obviously I had not!! :)

Comment: Updated. It's probably not the most graceful way to do it, but it seems like it gets the result you were intending.

Comment: Alton, thank you very much for that. I will test it as soon as I'll be in front of my pc and will let you know

Comment: Alton,
I am not sure what is wrong with it, but the code you suggested returns exactly equal counts for each value range, which may be ok for your data (because of how you generated it) but is not correct for mine.

Any idea on why this may be happening?

Comment: Alton, that one line has given me the answer I was searching for days!

Comment: now I just need to turn all of those commands into a formula that I can call for multiple files

Comment: Alton, can we possibly have a chat in pvt?

Comment: Yes. How can I contact you?

Comment: andrea.botti [at] gmail.com